# Which tag? wii-u or wiiu

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

New console incoming new 'which tag' quesion.

`wii-u` or `wiiu`

On official website is alwasy written **Wii U**, with single space between Wii and U, so I would suggest to use `wii-u` tag.

What do you think?

Comment: I think it's way too early to think about this :D

Comment: The first question is already arrived. I know we can change it later with a simple query, but if we are able (if we have enough info) to decide why not do immediately?

Comment: Somebody must've hurried for the Taxonomist badge :P

Comment: @badp Understandable, I miss Taxonomist badge too and I admit that I did the same for ps-vita :)

Comment: @badp - can you get more than one Taxonomist? (I already have it, for "Game-Mechanics", I believe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completed: [wii-u](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wii-u) ← [wiiu](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiiu)